# Connecting css, js, etc files to my Django rendered HTML webpage

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm trying to render my HTML webpage and I'm having some issues.

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Here is the TEMPLATES portion of my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['portfolio/PersonalSite',
                 'portfolio/PersonalSite/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                 'portfolio/PersonalSite/css/styles.css',
                 'portfolio/PersonalSite/js/scripts.min.js',
                 'portfolio/PersonalSite/files',
                 'portfolio/PersonalSite/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
                 'portfolio/PersonalSite/images/Guelph_Hacks_Logo.jpg',
                 'portfolio/PersonalSite/images/Tilt.jpg',
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**As you can see I tried to fix the problem by adding all the individual missing paths here but no luck unfortunately :(**

and here outputted error message:

```
Django version 2.0.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10678
Not Found: /libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:42] "GET /libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2178
Not Found: /css/styles.css
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:42] "GET /css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2094
Not Found: /css/bootstrap.min.css
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:42] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2115
Not Found: /images/Guelph_Hacks_Logo.jpg
Not Found: /js/scripts.min.js
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:42] "GET /images/Guelph_Hacks_Logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2136
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:42] "GET /js/scripts.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2103
Not Found: /images/Tilt.jpg
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:42] "GET /images/Tilt.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2097
Not Found: /j_icon.jpeg
[10/Jan/2018 16:54:42] "GET /j_icon.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 2085
```

If anyone could shed a little light on how I can properly fix this issue I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have the CSS etc in the html templates themselves?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/)? No need for luck - you afterwards just know how it works. ;) The term you are looking for is [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 0):

The good way to do your imports is to indicate the right directory

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portfolio' 'templates'),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

then from your HTML files, load and import statics
put this code in the top of your html page `{% load static %}`
and : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/styles.css" %}" />`
same syntax for the links of images and javascript